# How do I remove wet latex paint from carpet?

Tags: paint, cleaning, carpet

I have just stepped into latex paint and walked onto the carpet by accident. I haven't done anything yet it just happened.

How do I remove the paint from my carpet?

Answer (score 3):

You will be OK, it's only latex paint and you have time on your side.

1. Use a dry paper towel to suck up any wet paint.
2. Pour a bit of water on the dry paint to reactivate it.
3. Use a dry towel to dab the paint spot unit it goes away.

If the paint has been there awhile and has started to setup or if dabbing isn't doing the trick, you will have to scrub it. You can try warm water and a mild dish soap too.

**Warning:** Some people may advise rubbing alcohol or other solvents, be careful as these may strip the color or even melt the carpet depending on what your product is.

Still no luck? Try a professional carpet cleaner machine; the hot water and brushes will help scrape the paint out.

Edit: [found a nice video for you.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d5hZEIjxhEs)

Comment: **warm water** is a good start. As hot AF as you can get it is better.

Answer (score 1):

Blot up what you can with paper towels, rags, etc.

Wash and rinse a lot - use a wet vacuum to get the rinse water up. Takes a *lot* of rinsing.

Or don't worry about it until you are done painting, and then replace the carpet. Carpet is cheap, and truly satisfactory cleaning is difficult, especially if you don't have a wet vacuum or carpet cleaner standing by while you spill things on it - especially things that dry and become virtually impossible to remove.

Comment: Obviously you haven't priced out carpet recently to call it "cheap".

Comment: Compared tp hardwood or tile, the math still holds. Not to mention this post you are dropping a comment on is 7 years old.

Answer (score 1):

Blot up and the previous answers say. Blot, by just pressing down and not smearing. Then use warm water and dish soap to dissolve it. Use real cloth washcloths and not paper towels.  If it doesn't all come out, you could try some latex paint remove like "Goof Off", but be careful, it could hurt the carpet. There are milder version of goof off that are not so smelly (no solvents) that may work without less carpet damage. If you go to buy something, clover it with a piece of plastic wrap to keep it from drying out.

Answer (score 0):

If a small amount of dried paint (a drop) I some times cut the paint out of the carpet. Works for cigarette burns too.

Comment: This question specified _wet_ paint. The goal being to get it taken care of _before_ it dried and more drastic measures were necessary.